# FLECTRA ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

Tags: python

Estoy instalado onflectra 1.7 en windws, uso python 3.9 y cuando ejecuto pip.exe install -r requirements.txt obtengo este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto es StackOverflow en Español, por favor traduce tu pregunta utilizando el botón de `editar`. Además incluye el código de tu programa, está difícil ayudarte a depurar sin él y ver que es lo que estás haciendo que te causa ese error.

Comment: listo espero con eso puedan ayudarme , gracias

Comment: ¿Instalaste lasrdependencias de python? Los de [requirements.txt](https://doc.flectrahq.com/setup/install.html#id3)

Comment: cuales dependencias , Descargar archivo pip y ejecutar python get-pip.py , tambien pip install psycopg2 , estoy siguiendo este instructivo https://doc.flectrahq.com/setup/install.html#setup-install

Comment: No puedo ser más especifico, literalmente compartiste el mismo link. que yo.. Lee `Source installation requires manually installing dependencies`... Se requiere la instalación **manual** de independencias.

Answer (score 0):

In order to start the service, it is necessary to access the python.exe file that is in the project itself. This is done in the following way, it must be located in the server folder and execute:  & "C:\Program Files\Odoo 14.0.20201228\python\python.exe" odoo-bin -c odoo.conf
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]